# Redirect after purchasing

Tags: 8, commerce

How can I perform a redirect after purchasing a product? I tried to create a custom checkout pane for this purpose, but it doesn't work as the form is not submited:

```
public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
  if ($this->getStepId() == 'complete') {
    $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility to do this with a pane or do I have to create an event subscriber and redirect on the checkout event?

Answer (score 1):

In your "submitForm" method write below code:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
return;
```

To redirect you can also use the following code:

```
//after the namespace
use Drupal\Core\Url;

//In your "submitForm"
$url = Url::fromRoute('<front>');
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

To redirect you can also use the following code:

```
//after the namespace
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

//In your "submitForm"
global $base_url;
$response = new RedirectResponse($base_url);
$response->send();
return;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. My submitPaneForm is not called as my buildPaneForm is empty and does not trigger the submit function

Answer (score 1):

Examining CheckoutFlowBase::redirectToStep() taught me that this could be accomplished in a checkout pane like this:

```
use Drupal\commerce\Response\NeedsRedirectException;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

...

  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    throw new NeedsRedirectException(Url::fromUri('internal:/mydestination')->toString());
  }
```

Here's a configurable checkout pane for this purpose:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\commerce\Response\NeedsRedirectException;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the redirection pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "redirection",
 *   label = @Translation("Redirect"),
 * )
 */
class Redirection extends CheckoutPaneBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [
        'destination' => 'internal:/',
      ] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationSummary() {
      return $this->configuration['destination'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['destination'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Redirect to'),
      '#description' => "URI of the destination. For example 'internal:/search' or 'http://google.com'.",
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['destination'],
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    if (!$form_state->getErrors()) {
      $values = $form_state->getValue($form['#parents']);
      $this->configuration['destination'] = $values['destination'];
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    throw new NeedsRedirectException(Url::fromUri($this->configuration['destination'])->toString());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the redirect by setting the redirect in the submitPaneForm instead of the buildPaneForm function and attaching a JS to automatically submit the pane form.

I would prefer a solution without JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this feature just for some product variations then install the *Commerce Quick Purchase* module and create a block for each of those variations and in the block settings define whether you want a customer `Add to cart` product at all or just redirect to a product page or a Shopping cart page or checkout page. See more:
https://github.com/drugan/commerce_quick_purchase#redirection